# Executing events orderly inside a method in typescript with guarantee

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am making an app in `Ionic3`. The app requirement is that when I click a particular button following things executes in order:

1. All the button will on that page will be hidden
2. Taking Screenshot
3. Showing loader
4. Saving data through API
5. dismiss loader
6. share on Whatsapp
7. showing only necessary buttons after returning from whatsapp

Here is my code:

```
saveandshare() {
    this.homebtn = false;
    this.logout = false;
    this.back = false;
    this.save = false;

    let loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: 'Please wait...'
    });

    this.screenshot.URI(80).then(res => {
      this.screen = res.URI;
    });

    loading.present();

    this.share.testsubmit(this.screen).subscribe(
      data=>{
          console.log('Data Submnitted');
      })
      loading.dismiss();

      this.socialshare.shareViaWhatsApp('Test', this.screen, null).then(
        ()=>{  }
      )
    this.homebtn = true;
    this.logout = true;
  }
```

The code is running proper with no error but events are not `synchronous` like after building the app sometimes buttons are visible in screenshot, sometimes image is not there when I share on whatsapp, and in some cases after returning from whatsapp all buttons are visible and sometimes neither.

It seems that this is due to `asynchronous` nature of `javascript`. How do I make them to execute in order?

Please suggest me. Any help or suggestion would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: As your requirement is to sequentially executed steps(which you mentioned), you need to create separate functions for different tasks. And then, call them either in success handler function or use [async-await approach](https://javascript.info/async-await).

Comment: Thank you @Sujit. Can you please give a demonstration with example?

Comment: the approaches are simple enough. There are 2 ways of achieving the behavior which you require(1. success callback and 2. async-await). I can explain them, but it will be faster if you take look at [Asynchronous JavaScript](https://www.toptal.com/javascript/asynchronous-javascript-async-await-tutorial) or [Async JavaScript Approaches](https://stackify.com/async-javascript-approaches/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the explanation of how asynchronous functions can be handled in JavaScript.

Consider 2 functions which return asynchronously. It could be any network call as well.

```
function asyncA(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      resolve('Handled A()');
    }, 1000)
  });
}

function asyncB(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      resolve('Handled B()');
    }, 1000)
  });
}
```

**Method 1. Success handler callbacks -** Faster but has tight coupling

```
function callA(){
  asyncA().then(
    data => { 
      console.log(data);
      callB(); // continue calling other function
    },
    error => { console.log('Error while calling A()') }
  )
}

function callB(){
  asyncB().then(
    data => { 
      console.log(data);
      // continue calling if required.
      // Hide buttons
    },
    error => { console.log('Error while calling B()') }
  )
}

############### OR ##################

asyncA().then( data => { 
  console.log(data); // returned values from asyncA()
  return asyncB();
})
.then( data => { 
  console.log(data); // returned values from asyncB()
  // Hide buttons
});
```

**Method 2. async-await -** More understandable, loosely coupled, slow

```
async function callAll(){
  // make sure to handle errors using try { } cathc(err){ }
  let a_val = await asyncA();
  let b_val = await asyncB();
  console.log(a_val, b_val);

  // all functions have returned, hide buttons
}
```

Depending on your requirements, you need to choose any or both mentioned approaches.

I will go with 1st method(mentioned above). Below are sequence which I would follow() to achieve required functionality. Make sure to handle error cases.

```
this.screenshot.URI(80).then(res => {
  console.log('Screenshot API finished');
  this.screen = res.URI;
  loading.present();

  // create separate function for below code
  this.share.testsubmit(this.screen).subscribe(
    data=>{
      console.log('Data Submmitted');
      loading.dismiss();

      // create separate function for below code
      this.socialshare.shareViaWhatsApp('Test', this.screen, null).then(
        ()=>{
          // shraing completed
          // perform final actions. Create separate funcitons if required
          this.homebtn = true;
          this.logout = true;
        }
      );
    });
});
```

Try to experiment between both methods which I have mentioned and choose the best one according to your requirement.

Comment: Thank You @Sujit. That really helped. So, in my case I have to make functions for each task like `asyncA()` that you have shown in your example. Is it compulsory to return promise in each method like `asyncA()`?

Comment: I think all of your functions are already returning either Promise or Observable, you don't need to return explicitly(unless required). I will extend my answer so that it will be more specific to your requirement. You may need to modify it, but it will mostly follow the same approach.